# Analytics: Test events not showing up - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: google-analytics

I've got 3 profiles: Master, Raw Data, and Test, on the Test profile I have no filters configured.

I want to test using some events.

I created a local HTML file as shown below to generate some test data that I could play with in Analytics. But the events never showed up in Analytics. I wonder what I might be doing wrong? Is the lack of a domain an issue maybe?

```
<html><head></head><body>Login_popup_complete_Facebook

<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-28554309-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Login popup completed', 'Facebook']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the test page needs to be served from a webserver, when I load them from apache I see the Analytics requests in FireBug, but when I load them directly from a file I don't see any calls to Analytics in firebug.